# Homophone Riddle 5

Tags: riddle, word

Didn't make one in quite a while so here you go:

```
You use me every day,
Or have chipped something away yesterday
You probably won't see me every day,
But in some places, they are on display
And if you get too nosy,
This is what someone would say
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be

> mind/mined?

You use me every day,

> Mind

Or have chipped something away yesterday

You probably won't see me every day,
But in some places, they are on display

> Mined gold and things?

And if you get too nosy,
This is what someone would say

> Mind your own business

Comment: The line "You probably won't see me every day, But in some places, they are on display" the explanation is not the intended one but nice job! +1 :)

Comment: I was just gonna ask you what the answer was for that and for "chipped something away yesterday" :)

Comment: The answer is mind to brain and in museums (some of them) there are brains and stuff

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry I missed it :)